# Bootstrap 5 default nav opens outside of screen on phones

Tags: navigation, bootstrap-5

My problem is very strange, I'm using a default boostrap 5 menu, basically straight from their website: It looks and works perfect in mozilla dev view, but on a real phone it opens off screen. (as if it was opening from the top of my screen, both upwards and downwards starting from the middle.)

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7W3C.png)

The code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0 mx-lg-4">
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-4 mx-lg-0" href="index.html" >KOUSHNA NAVABI</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler mx-sm-4 mx-lg-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-center mx-auto menupoints full-width">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="projects.html">News</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="archive.html">Project Archive</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="texts.html">Texts</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="publications.html">Publications</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="editions.html">Editions</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link mx-2" href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
 .navbar {
    height: 5rem;
  }
  @media (max-width: 768px) { 
    .navbar {
    height: 5rem;
  }}
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) { 
    .navbar-nav {background: white; padding-top: 3rem;overflow-y: scroll!important;}
}

@media (max-width: 768px) { 
  .full-width {  height: 100vh; background: rgb(255, 255, 255)!important; margin-top: 2rem!important;} 
}
  .navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif!important;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .navbar-brand {
      letter-spacing: .1rem;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      
    }
  }

  .nav-link {
    text-decoration: none; color: var(--primary-color); 
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 14px;
  }

  .menupoints {
    font-size: 1.5rem!important;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .menupoints{
      font-size: 1.8rem!important;
      line-height: 4rem;
  }}
  @media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .menupoints{
      
      font-size: 1.1rem!important;
  }}
  .navbar-toggler {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    }
```

I thought I made a mess somewhere, so started with a clean slate, but it looks the same again after a few hours of work.
Thank you,
D

I don't understand this section, that's what I wrote above. Is this to prove that I sweated enough?

Comment: Edit:

I can't get any bootstrap 5 navbars to be full screen when opened.

Not even their own examples

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after a few hours of frustration.

I set a height for.navbar and this somehow made it freak out